# Showing that a ring homomorphism induces a correspondence that maps free modules to free modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

Let $f: \Lambda \rightarrow \Lambda'$ be a ring homomorphism. This induces a mapping $M \mapsto \Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda} M$, where $M$ is a $\Lambda$-module and $\Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda} M$ is a $\Lambda'$- module. I want to show that if $M$ is free, $\Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda}M$ is free.

My attempt:

Let $\left\{x_i\right\}$ be a basis for $M$. I claim that $\left\{1_{\Lambda'} \otimes x_i\right\}$ form a basis for $\Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda} M$. Given $\lambda' \otimes m \in \Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda} M$,
\begin{align*}
\lambda' \otimes m &= \lambda' (1_{\Lambda'} \otimes m) \\
                   &= \lambda' (1_{\Lambda'} \otimes (\lambda_1 x_1 + \dots  +                                \lambda_n x_n)) \\
                   &= \lambda' \lambda_1 (1 \otimes x_1) + \dots + \lambda' \lambda_n (1 \otimes x_n)
\end{align*} 
for some $\lambda_i \in \Lambda$.

I think I'm on the right track, but I don't know how to reconcile the products $\lambda' \lambda_i$ since at first glance this product has no reason why it would make sense. I feel like I have to use that $f$ is a homomorphism from $\Lambda$ to $\Lambda'$, but I"m not sure how. Can we just consider $\Lambda'$ a $\Lambda$-module and make these problems go away?

Comment: $M$ is free as $\Lambda$-module then $M$ is isomorphic to $\oplus \Lambda.$ Hence $\Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda}M$ is isomorphic to $\oplus \Lambda '.$ So $\Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda}M$ is free as $\Lambda '$-module

Answer (score 1):

By [Hungerford's Algebra book page 181](https://books.google.com/books?id=t6N_tOQhafoC&q=has+a+nonemptybasis#v=onepage&q&f=false):
If $M$ is free as $\Lambda$-module, then $M$ is isomorphic to $\oplus \Lambda.$ Hence $\Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda}M$ is isomorphic to $\oplus \Lambda '.$ So $\Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda}M$ is free as $\Lambda '$-module.

Comment: page 213 of book says tensor product  commutes with direct sum. so $\Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda}M\cong \Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda}(\oplus \Lambda)\cong $$ \oplus (\Lambda' \otimes_{\Lambda}\Lambda)\cong \oplus \Lambda '.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\Lambda'$ is a $\Lambda$-module via $f$: set $\lambda\lambda'=f(\lambda)\lambda'$.

But you still need to prove the linear independence of $(1_{\Lambda'} \otimes x_i)$ , and this is not obvious.

Answer (score 1):

From the abstract nonsense point of view: The tensor product is left adjoint to the Hom-Functor, hence it commutes with arbitrary colimits, in particular with direct sums.